# Removing/destroying child object that belongs_to 2 parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :documents, :uniq => true 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents #???, :allow_destroy => true

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :document, :validate => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :document #???, :allow_destroy => true

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist  
    belongs_to :concert
```

I want to remove a document from concerts: Destroy it, if its only parent is a concert, but set concert_id to nil and save document, if it also belongs_to an artist. (and analogue idea from artist point of view)

I would like to either:

- In artist and concert class intercept `.marked_for_destruction`? And stop destruction of document if it is referenced by the other parent. How do I do that?

Or even better:

- Add a before_destroy callback in document class that checks if this document has a (live) second parent, but then I'd need to know which class (parent) is calling destroy, so I'd know which foreign key to remove. How do I know which parent is calling destroy?

I have explored polymorphic associations, but I need the SAME document to belong_to 2 parents.

Have lost the plot if it makes any difference, but for completeness sake: Concert and Artist are in a has_many :through => :engagements association

Adding this in Concert (and  analogue in Artist) as before_save callbacks works:

```
def documents_for_deletion?
  self.documents.each do |doc| 
    if doc.marked_for_destruction?
      unless doc.artist_id.blank?
        doc.reload
        doc.concert_id = nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Is there a way to do it in Document as a before_destroy callback? (which I would prefer, see above)

Answer (score 1):

You can use association callbacks, like after_remove:

```
class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, :uniq => true, :after_remove => :destroy_document_with_no_parent

def destroy_document_with_no_parent(removed_document)
  removed_document.destroy unless removed_document.concert_id || removed_document.artist_id
end
```

You probably should place the method in some helper so you wouldn't need to repeat the code in two classes.

Comment: after_remove cannot stop destruction, neither can before_remove. unless you set     `accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents, :allow_destroy => true`    above callbacks are not available. you can only stop destruction from the parent model, with `document.reload` which clears the `.marked_for_destruction`

Comment: removing from association does not destroy the removed object.